# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 in a system which has already Ubuntu 13.04 and windows 8 by replacing the previous ubuntu version

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 without upgrading the Ubuntu 13.04. Please suggest whether, it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible and also pretty easy.

1. Burn Ubuntu 14.04 to a CD or USB drive and boot into the setup.
2. When confronted with the screen asking where you want to install Ubuntu, select "Erase Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu 14.04". WARNING: Make sure you select this and not the option to erase the disk! The option you want to select is most likely the second one, but MAKE SURE!
3. Install Ubuntu.

Comment: hi, i want to remove the existing ubuntu 13.04 and in place of that, i want to install the lts version of ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @U-571 You might want to edit your question if that's what you want. What I got was that you wanted 13.04, 14.04 and Windows at the same time. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hi, Zacharee1 After installation the ubuntui 14.04, I am not able to install softwares with sudo user.

Comment: `sudo` user? Do you type `su` or `sudo` and what happens?